# PHP Target a specific item in array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, laravel-blade

I'm using ACF and I'm trying to split repeater items into two columns using a foreach loop. But I'm stuck at actually getting a specific item out of the array. Btw I'm quite new to PHP so forgive me if I'm using a wrong term, I hope you still understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

This is what I think I need to do:

1. make a count variable and make two empty arrays ($column_left and $column_right) that hold the items from the foreach.
2. make an if statement to check if the count is divisible by 2 then store the items into $column_left else store them in the column_right variable.

Now so far I got that done like this:

```
<div class="row">
                @php
                    $column_left = [];
                    $column_right = [];
                    $count = 0;
                @endphp

                @foreach ($accordion_items as $item)
                    @if ($count % 2 == 0)
                        @php
                            $column_left[] = $item;
                        @endphp
                    @else
                        @php
                            $column_right[] = $item;
                        @endphp   
                    @endif

                    @php
                        $count++;
                    @endphp
                @endforeach

                @php
                    var_dump($column_left);
                @endphp
            </div>
```

The var_dump actually shows what I need so I know I am quite warm. This is a small piece of what the var_dump printed:

```
array(4) { [0]=> array(3) { ["accordion_icon"]=> array(24) { ["ID"]=> int(160) ["id"]=> int(160) ["title"]=> string(14) "wordpress-icon" ["filename"]=> string(18) "wordpress-icon.png" ["filesize"]=> int(969) ["url"]=> string(74) "http://localhost/new-site/web/app/uploads/wordpress-icon.png" ["link"]=> string(78) "http://localhost/new-site/web/what-is-new/test/wordpress-icon/"
```

How do I modify my var_dump so I can see a certain item from this array? Like for instance the "['URL']" part

Comment: $arrayvariable[0]['url'] url of first record in array. 0 is for first record. use foreach for more control

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think I got it. I made a foreach now for both arrays left and right and outputted the url the way you showed.. now I'm getting 4 urls!